# Combining Query Result sets in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to combine multiple query result sets in oracle SQL

The sample Query is

Select * 
from table where 
table.id in

(

```
   (
    select table.id 
    from table 
    where cond 1 

    intersect

    select table.id 
    from table 
    where cond 2   
   )
```

union
       (

```
    select table.id 
    from table 
    where cond 3   

    intersect

    select table.id 
    from table 
    where cond 4
```

)
)

I want to get the intersect result first and then union should be applied how to combine two result sets like these ?

Comment: What do you mean by get the intersect result first? This query doesn't give you the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing this?

```
Select *
from table
where ((cond 1) and (cond 2)) or
      ((cond 3) and (cond 4));
```

Comment: so the answer should be like Select *
from table
where table.id in  ((query1) and (query2)) or
      ((query 3) and (query 4));